# メニューバーのリンクが自動でアクティブ化しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

※[他質問サイト](https://teratail.com/questions/jk5yzgfjbmj4aj)でも同様の質問をしています。解決した場合はそちらも更新します。よろしくお願いします。

#### 前提・実現したいこと

rails、bootstrapでメニューバーを作成しています。
現在表示しているページのリンクを自動でアクティブな状態にしたいです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

アクティブな状態が実装できません。
以下記事を参考に作成しました。
[サイドメニューのアクティブ・非アクティブ化](https://study-diary.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2020/09/05/190836)

[image: イメージ説明]

#### 該当のソースコード

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper
（省略）
  def active_if(path)
    path == controller_path ? 'active' : ''
  end
end
```

```
app/views/users/_sidebar.html.erb

<div class="col-auto col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-light">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
      <li class="nav-item">

<!-- 該当のコード -->
        <%= link_to mypage_path, class: "nav-link align-middle px-0 #{active_if('mypage')}" do %>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">マイページ</span>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to profile_path, class: "nav-link align-middle px-0 #{active_if('profile')}" do %>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">プロフィール</span>
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'mypage', to: 'users#mypage'
（省略）
  resource :profile
（省略）
end
```

#### 試したこと

classに手動でactiveを付与するとアクティブな状態になるため、
ヘルパーに問題があると思いますが、
参考記事と同じコードを使用しているのに実装できない原因がわかりません。
恐れ入りますがよろしくお願いいたします。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby: 3.0.2
rails: 6.0.4
Bootstrap: 5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get 'mypage', to: 'users#mypage'`というroutesの場合`/mypage`の時`controller_path`は`users`を返すので`class: "nav-link align-middle px-0 #{active_if('users')}"`だと`active`が付与されると思います。

こう言った時は`binding.pry`で覗いてみるとすぐ問題点がわかります。

```ruby
  def active_if(path)
    binding.pry
    path == controller_path ? 'active' : ''
  end
```

本題とはそれますがコントローラーだけで判断するのは余計な時にも`active`がついちゃいそうなので、私は以前、こんな感じのヘルパーを作ったことがあります。

```ruby
def current_page?(arg)
  arg.keys.all? {|key| params[key] == arg[key] }
end
```

使う時はこんな感じ

```ruby
current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'mypage')
```

(このコード動かしてないのでダメだったら適当に修正お願いします)

あと、手前味噌ですがHTMLのclassを動的に付与する場合[classnames-rails-view](https://github.com/gomo/classnames-rails-view)を使うと便利ですよ。jsで有名な[classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames)のマネですけど。

これを使えばこんな感じになります。

```erb
<%= link_to mypage_path, class: class_names('nav-link align-middle px-0', 'active': current_page?(controller: 'users', action: 'mypage')) do %>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">マイページ</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: 返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません！頂いた回答で無事実装することができました。ご丁寧に教えていただき有難うございました！

せっかくですので追加で教えていただいた以下コードもマスターしたいのですが、
エラーが生じましたのでよろしければ解説をお願いしたいです。

`
def current_page?(arg)
  arg.keys.all? {|key| params[key] == arg[key] }
end
`

Comment: 発生したエラー:
`undefined method 'keys' for "/":String(NoMethodError)`

ビューから受け取った引数`{:controller=>"users", :action=>"mypage”}`を`keys.all?`メソッドでハッシュに含まれるキーの一覧を配列として取得、配列の中の値が表示しているビューと全て合っていれば`{|key| params[key] == arg[key] }`、trueを返しクラスに`active`を付与するヘルパーだと解釈したのですが、合っていますでしょうか？

また、わからない点がありまして、ハッシュのvalueではなくkeyを取得する理由は何でしょうか？ハッシュのキーはcontrollerとactionなので全てのビューで一致してしまうのではないかと思いました。
お手数おかけします。

Comment: 読みづらいコメント申し訳ございません